# When using Emotion-React together with Typescript, what is the difference between Props and InnerProps?

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I'm trying to add types to my StyledComponents (Emotion-React). 
Lets say I have a styled Button component, when I declare it's type with the generic StyledComponent I'm required to pass 3 type variables to it:

```
const Button : StyledComponent<Props, InnerProps, Theme> = 
    styled("button")`
        cssProp:cssVal:
    `
```

What is the difference between Props and InnerProps? Are InnerProps simply the children?

Answer (score 0):

From [emotion github:](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/2efe235efa5de4b5ca01af3d6ff7047215af43d5/packages/styled-base/types/index.d.ts)

- `InnerProps` is type parameter that represents props type of
- internal component (target of styling)
- `ExtraProps` is type parameter that represents extra props type of
- styled component.

Comment: Thanks. I find it a bit peculiar - I use components as wrapers, and pass them as children various kinds of React elements. In the code I write these wrappers are ignorant regarding the children they might receive.

Comment: can you share an example?